# Manipulating <canvas> image data in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, firefox-addon, thunderbird-addon

In my extension I'd like to manipulate some images. So I'm trying to read their raw pixels using canvas. 
The problem is that if, in chrome code, I execute (`img` is an image in a content document):

```
var src = document.createElement("canvas");
src.width = img.naturalWidth;
src.height = img.naturalHeight;
var srcCtx = src.getContext("2d");
```

on the last line it says that `getContext` is not a function.
On the other hand if I run (notice that the first line is different!):

```
var src = img.ownerDocument.createElement("canvas");
src.width = img.naturalWidth;
src.height = img.naturalHeight;
var srcCtx = src.getContext("2d");
srcCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var src_data = srcCtx.getImageData(0, 0, src.width, src.height);
```

no error is returned, but `src_data` comes out empty. I suppose it may have something to do with accessing web content from chrome code. Any suggestion?

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem elsewhere in the code.

Comment: When you find the problem yourself, it's good to post it as an answer to your own question for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said above, the problem was in a different piece of code.

It was actually due to the fact that I misread the documentation and thought that `src_data` was supposed to contain the pixels, whereas it should have been `src_data.data`. For some reason that I can't understand printing out `uneval(src_data)` would return `({})` instead, whereas in it there should be three members, `data`, `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem with the first snippet is that `document` is a XUL document, so its `createElement` function will create a XUL element and there is no such thing as a XUL:canvas. It is possible to create HTML elements in a XUL document, but then you'll want to use [createElementNS()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS). To be more clear the code would look like

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "canvas");
```

Why `src_data` comes out empty though, I don't know.

Comment: can you tell me with which `NameSpace` can we create a `canvas` element from the firefox extension. I'm struggling a lot and getting the following error when I tried creating `canvas` using `document.createElement("canvas");
`

`NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE
Component is not available`

Comment: Canvas is an HTML element, so you need the HTML (or XHTML) namespace, `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
content.document.createElement()
```